# why we use char array to create a buffer

Tags: c

Why we use a char array to create a buffer in the memory instead of a int array and if int array can be used to create the buffer,how to get the output from it ?

```
int main()
{
    char  buffer[100];
    fread(buffer,sizeof(int),4,stdin);
    int i=0;
    while(i<4)
    {
        printf ("%d,\n",buffer[i]);
        i=i+1;
    }    
}
```

Comment: We use `char` because it's logical. It represents one character (usually) in the ASCII encoding, according to ANSI C. Things get odd if you are dealing with Unicode, however.

Comment: @user1781308 - I'm not sure why you're being kicked around so brutally.  Sorry :(.  A few comments: 1) a char is not an int.  But both are integral values.  2) "buffers" are traditionally arrays of byte.  But they don't *need* to be.  Your buffer can be double[], some_struct[] or, in your case, int[].  3) "fread()" can accomodate buffers of different element widths (like int vs. char).  low-level "read()" and "write() - or socket reads and writes - expect byte buffers only.  'Hope that helps..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very simply: we use a char array if we want to read bytes.

Either text strings, or (more generally), binary objects.

A "byte" is usually 1/4 the size of an "int".

Moreover, socket "read" and "write" counts are byte counts. By longstanding convention, they expect byte buffers.

'Hope that helps!

Comment: what if, i want to use an int array to create the buffer..?

Comment: You can :).  Your fread() example does exactly that.  See my notes above, however.

Answer (score 1):

Because `char` in the `C` language is exactly 1 byte. So it's logical to write in the file byte by byte.

Comment: Minor correction - there is no *requirement* for a byte to be 8 bits: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte